# Secure Connection Failed when run asp.net mvc application with ssl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, ssl, settings

I set using in my asp.net mvc application `SSL Enabled = true` (so now is `https://localhost:63892/` and `http://localhost:12555/`, but when I run application via Debug, it said "Secure Connection Failed". What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the self-signed certificate that Visual Studio generated is trusted. The certificate is called IIS Express Development Certificate

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate.aspx

Comment: I also had this problem. After `trusting` the `certificate`, I was able to access with `https` in debug mode. But after deploying the app, I can't access with `https`. Any idea why?

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib After deploying, the app lives on a different domain. You'll need a valid cert for that domain to be served.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding this in case if helps anyone:* Using VisualStudio 2015, Windows 10, and IIS10 Express, even though I added the certificate I still wasnt able to access localhost over HTTPS. I resolved by uninstalling IIS10 Express and install IIS8 Express. I was then able to access localhost over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you able to find a proper solution for IIS10 Express? I'm having the same issue right now even though my certificate is trusted and SSL enabled in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: unfortunately no, I have no clue as why.. so ended up using IIS8 express !

Comment: I found a solution to this problem on VisualStudio 2015 with IIS10 Express, I wrote an answer to this topic in case of anyone might face with the same issue, but it is removed because I didn't give enough details about the answer. Anyway, you can find the solution in this link: https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0
Basically, chrome does not accept you default certificate for IIS Express 10 and you have to create a new one. This link provides a tool to make it easy and I could be able to solve this easily.

Comment: Thanks & sure, i will try that out !